# TinkerPop get the count and continue the same traversal

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I'm currently using TinkerPop java APIs for graph traversal. Currently I had to create a duplicate copy of the same traversal to compute the count.

```
Long allUsersCount = gt.V().hasLabel("user").has("name", "John").count().next();
List<Vertex> users = gt.V().hasLabel("user").has("name", "John").toList();
```

When I tried to reuse the traversal returned by `gt.V().hasLabel("user").has("name", "John").count()` to get the list, it caused the error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The traversal strategies are complete
>   and the traversal can no longer be modulated

I just want to know if there is any way to avoid this repetition as the traversal is same for both cases `gt.V().hasLabel("user").has("name", "John")` just the terminating operations are different.

Is there any way to store the count in-between(inside a java variable) and continue the traversal to get the list of users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `count()` step is a "reducing barrier step" which is why you see the behavior you do. There are many ways to work around this. Here is one example that uses the air-routes data set.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('city','London').
               fold().
               project('cities','count').
                 by().
                 by(count(local))

==>[cities:[v[49],v[50],v[88],v[94],v[206],v[649]],count:6]
```

Comment: I'm still learning the ins and outs of Gremlin, and this was very helpful!  My requirement was to return a count with just the first instance from the set of objects alongside the total count, so I used `fold()` like you did above, and combined that with `unfold().limit(1)` in the projection.
```...fold().project('city','count').by(unfold().limit(1)).by(count(local))```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by projecting your results and using a count() step with a local scope.

```
g.V().fold().project('cnt', 'edges').by(count(local)).by()
```

returns this:

```
==>[cnt:6,edges:[v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4],v[5],v[6]]]
```

Local scope (i.e. count(local)) will perform the desired operation on each list inside the current object.  In this case we are finding all vertices, collecting them into a list.  Once we are in the project() we are then counting the local scope (i.e. the number of items in the list) and returning that count along with the original list.